# How to specify absolute path when the program parses relative path?

Tags: javascript, relative-path, absolute-path

I'm using a Javascript library which takes a string specifying a *relative* path as an option. Using this path, it loads a CSS files which is used for the theme. However, I have placed the themes files elsewhere and want to reference this using an *absolute* path instead.

This path is relative to the page which calls it. So if the path I gave was `/absolute/path/file.js`, and I am on `[host]/abc/def/ghi`, it will call `[host]/abc/def/ghi/absolute/path/file.js`. If I am on `[host]/xyz`, it will call `[host]/xyz/absolute/path/file.js`

I cannot simple go up two or three levels `../../` because that might not be the root directory. Instead, I am doing `../../../../../../../../absolute/path/here.css`, to ensure it goes as far back as practically necessary, which does work.

There are no option in the library to use base path.

**Is there a more *elegant* way to specify an absolute path when the library parses only relative paths?**

Comment: Which library is it? I would almost think this is a bug. You have specified an absolute path starting with a `/`? Or starting with `http://`?

Comment: Normally you can use "/path/to/file.css" to go from the web root folder.

Comment: @GolezTrol Confession: I am using [Epic Editor](http://epiceditor.com/). When I first wrote the question, I thought it didn't let me specify a base path, but indeed it does. But I still want to know a solution for future reference, in case I do need to use a poorly-written library which doesn't have an option to use absolute paths.